# How can I get the process ID using Java for Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu, process

Firstly, I ran the sample.jar with **"java -jar sample.jar"** command in bash.

Then trying to execute the **"ps -ef | grep "sample.jar""**
command in Linux with Java and to get the process ID on which the sample.jar is running.

```
String cmd = "ps -ef | grep \"sample.jar\"";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
```

But by the following code I couldn't find the process ID:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String s = null;
if ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    String str[] = s.split("\\s+", 3);
    String processId = str[1]; // I need this processId
    rt.exec("kill " + processId);
}
```

**I want to find the process id and kill the process.
So that I can re-run my spring boot project on the same port.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `kill`, you can use the [`proc.destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) or the [`proc.forciblyDestroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroyForcibly--) methods, which does effectively the same thing and has the added bonus of being cross platform!

Comment: Ok I will use destroy() method. But I need the process Id first.

Comment: if you already have the Process object that you created in `Process proc = rt.exec(cmd)`, you can call `proc.destroy()` instead of `rt.exec(...)`. You have to still have access to the process object because you called `proc.getInputStream()` a few lines earlier.

Comment: Firstly, I ran the sample.jar with **"java -jar sample.jar"** command in bash.

Then trying to execute the **"ps -ef | grep "sample.jar""**
command in Linux with Java and to get the process ID on which the sample.jar is running.